# Why did I just start getting "Group authorization failed" on Kafka using Confluent for a .Net Consumer

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I have a Kafka consumer which had been working for months but now I receive the following:
*Broker: Group authorization failed*

What might have changed in the environment that would cause this error?

GroupId looks to be a required field for any Kafka consumer so I'm not getting what is happening.
I'm using Confluent.Kafka 1.3.0

Comment: Maybe there was a change in your kafka brokers? I've seen this kind of error, when I was trying to consume a topic, but I was missing some permissions.

Comment: I have seen this error today using Confluent Cloud. I discovered that administrators were restricting access to topics and consumer groups based on the API key they generated, forcing us to use use a prefix on the topic identify the team using the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem but it may not apply to others.
I first saw this error when running/debugging in VS.

After going around and around it turns out that in my environment, which is VS2017 on Win10, that Kafka under the covers uses Kerberos to get the credentials for the executing user and passes those credentials to validate access to Kafka. So in a Windows 10 environment that means Kerberos uses Active Directory and passes my AD id.

And no you can't change and use an alternative like a Keytab file.

So bottom-line is that Kafka admins had made some changes to Windows AD groups which removed my NTID.  The admins were trying to limit access by only system Ids.  After discovering this I asked to be re-instated into the AD groups and all is well now.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue and the comment made by  Mário Meyrelles helped me.

```
props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "your-name-of-application-here");
```

This guy needed to have a starting prefix without which it would not permit.

Comment: there is defintely something with naming convention